# I need hyphen in my URL

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

My URL `page.php?title=this%20is%20a%20page` is fetching from MySQL database and it works good with `%20` (space). But when i use hyphen the values not fetching from database, what do i have to do now?

I try make an another field in database name url and i used hyphen
instead of space but still not working `page.php?url=this-is-a-page`

Give me any suggestion guys so my URL will work pretty, good looking and easy to understand.

Comment: Show the PHP code and the DB record you are trying to select,

Comment: There's nothing special about hyphen in URLs. The problem must be in your PHP code.

Comment: can u suggest me what type of problem possibly can occur in php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyphen is `%2D` when URL encoded.

Comment: Hyphen doesn't need to be encoded, it has no special meaning.